# MonoTouch for iPhone: how to make a UIButton focus?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitextfield

I have two UITextFields and one button on the view. I want user to be able to loop through the three controls using tab or return key. However, I can only make them loop through the TextFields. Here is my code in ViewDidLoad():

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        tfFirstName.BecomeFirstResponder();
        tfFirstName.ShouldReturn = delegate
        {
            tfLastName.BecomeFirstResponder(); // move focus to LastName field
            return true;
        };
        tfLastName.ShouldReturn = delegate
        {
            btnOK.BecomeFirstResponder(); // move focus to OK button
            btnOK.ResignFirstResponder(); // hide the keyboard
            return true;
        };
    }
```

In IB, I also changed "Return Key" to "Next" for the two text fields.

It appears to me that the `tfFirstName.ShouldReturn` delegate works, but `tfLastName.ShouldReturn` doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A touch based application doesn't really have the concept of "focus" the way a mouse/keyboard based application does.  Assigning "focus" to a control that doesn't accept keyboard input (like a button) doesn't make sense.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I'm just playing with the simulator right now.

Comment: Nice point, makes sense. Even I had this question since I was working into simulator, but you cleared it.